# mysql default value?

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my database, is it standard to leave most fields with default value "none"? For example a user id, a post title, category, or tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For required fields such as username or password, you should set `NOT NULL`. For other optional fields you can set it to `NULL`. For numbers, it is almost always a good idea to set default value to zero `0` .

Comment: Thanks!! By `NOT NULL` do you mean just set the default to `none` and null to `no`?

Comment: @CyberJunkie: yeah you can interpret that way :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your question as I best understand it.

For `User_id`, it is common to set its default value to `auto_increment`. SQL will automatically fill this in when you create a new record.

Text fields will default to null, although when you create the table you can set a `DEFAULT` such as ' ', 'cat' or anything else you like.